# Sum fastest scores (points) for same person on different tracks

Tags: php, mysql, sum, points

I need to calculate total points (`cn_category.category_points`) for every player (`cn_players` record). This is driven by the table `cn_records`, which contains both current and obsolete records. I need to sum only the best times for all categories (`cn_category` records), maps (`cn_maps` records; not shown below), and games (`cn_wads` records; not shown below). Also, for categories #9, #10, and #11, points are awarded for the *three* best scores/records, instead of just the very best.

I have this query so far, but it counts both current and obsolete records:

```
SELECT *, MIN(r.record_time), SUM(cn_category.category_points)
FROM (select * from cn_records as r order by r.record_time ASC) AS r
LEFT JOIN cn_players ON r.player1_id = cn_players.player_id
LEFT JOIN cn_category ON r.category_id = cn_category.category_id
WHERE r.category_id BETWEEN 1 AND 25
GROUP BY r.player1_id
ORDER BY SUM(category_points), r.player1_id DESC
```

(Note: The above is not the complete query. A few joins and `WHERE`-clause conditions have been removed for simplicity's sake.)

Categories are in the `cn_category` table:

```
 category_id | category_points | ...
-------------+-----------------+-----
           1 |             1.0 | ...
           9 |             5.0 | ...
         ... |             ... | ...
```

Players are in the `cn_players` table:

```
 player_id | ...
-----------+-----
         1 | ...
         2 | ...
       ... | ...
```

"Records" are in the `cn_records` table (which has thousands of rows):

```
 record_id | category_id | player1_id | record_time | ...
-----------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----
         1 |           1 |        143 |    00:00:00 | ...
         2 |           1 |        145 |    00:00:00 | ...
         3 |           1 |         41 |    00:00:00 | ...
         4 |           1 |         41 |    00:00:00 | ...
         5 |           1 |        141 |    00:00:00 | ...
         6 |           1 |         41 |    00:00:00 | ...
       ... |         ... |        ... |         ... | ...
```

Comment: Please excuse: Too much noise to answer.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on just the important information, in a readable way. If I've removed anything that really needs to be in the question, please feel free to re-add it.

Comment: Couple comments. Prefix `category_points` with a table, it may be too ambiguous for the aggregate to work. If your `r.category_id` is sequential `1 => 25` use the `BETWEEN` operator.

Comment: Are these two `JOIN`s identical for a purpose? `JOIN cn_players AS a ON (r.player1_id = a.player_id)` vs `LEFT JOIN cn_players ON r.player1_id = cn_players.player_id`

Comment: Ok, replaced 'BETWEEN' and changed prefix. Sorry 'JOIN' is not needed, I've just started with MySQL/PHP and I was using this example and applied it: forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,193658,193658#msg-193658

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You start with selecting the max points per category from the cn_records table. Then you can join the cn_records table again to select only the actual records per category (the ones that match the max points).

After that, you can join player and category details and do additional grouping and filtering as you like. The hard part is done. :)

```
SELECT
    p.player_id,
    p.player_name,
    sum(c.category_points) AS total_points
FROM
    /* Select the max points per category */
    (SELECT
      r.category_id,
      min(r.record_time) AS best_time
    FROM
      cn_records r
    GROUP BY
      r.category_id) ar /* Actual records */
    /* Join the records table to find the records that match the max points.
       These are the only records to investigate */
    INNER JOIN cn_records r 
      ON r.category_id = ar.category_id 
      AND r.record_time = ar.best_time
    /* Inner (don't left) join player. What is a record without player */
    INNER JOIN cn_players p ON r.player1_id = p.player_id
    INNER JOIN cn_category c ON r.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY
    r.category_id
```

Comment: I've tried to run it and I get: _Unknown column 'r.category_points'_  on _sum(r.category_points)_ and _MAX(r.category_points)_ Need to figure it out :)

Comment: I think it should be `record_time` instead of `category_points`.

Comment: Yes, I thought category_points was a field in record. Now, instead of max(r.category_points) I changed it to min(r.record_time), which should give you the lowest (best) time. In the query result, sum(c.category_points) is used, so the player gets the category_points for all categories in which he has the best time.

Comment: `p.player_name,` also reports unknown column, but if I remove it query executes. But it's not working ok since it shows same players twice or more. There are 11 wads (games), 25 categories and 83 maps so all of them should be taken into consideration when calculating highscores for players. There is a best record for each wad, map and category.

Comment: For example this query shows best records for game 1 and category 1 on all maps in game 1:  

    SELECT *, MIN(r.record_time) FROM (SELECT * FROM cn_records AS r ORDER BY r.record_time ASC) AS r  
    WHERE r.wad_id = 1 AND r.category_id = 1 GROUP BY r.map_id

Comment: And did you book any progress in the full month since my answer, or are you sitting back, hoping for an additional comment?

Comment: To be honest I didn't have time to work with this at all, I have time today that's why I posted link to db, atm. I'm trying out your sample but can't figure SELECT in brackets. afaik that SELECT will ignore map and game, so it outputs only 29 records since there are 29 categories, to make it work properlyit should output ~2900 records (maps * categories * wads). Please, understand that I understand only basic MySQL stuff so sorry for stupid questions.